# When using ajax with django views, when should I use a method of GET and when should it be POST?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm able to accomplish the same task with either--I only need to make sure that if the ajax method is get, then my view needs to handle the `get` and if a POST, that the view handles a `post`.

Given this, when do I use a GET and when do I use a POST?

```
$.ajax({
            method: "????",
            url: $endpoint,
            data: $buttonData,
            success: handleSuccess,
            error: handleError,
        })  

class MyAjaxView(View):

    def ???(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, POST is used to "send" something to the server, while GET is used to "fetch" something from the server.  It's a good idea to follow the these conventions because that's how must APIs also work.

For reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: What if I'm simply using ajax to send a signal to the server in order to update some other data?

Comment: @Homer in that case is a PUT or PATCH. Look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Comment: Is there a practical difference when using put or patch in regards to django? Since theres no put or patch class functions.